# Frequency Modulation Sideband Amplitude

Tags: communication

How to find the amplitudes of sidebands for the frequency modulation? From the bessel table, I have obtained the relative amplitudes but not for the amplitudes. Some of the info given are peak freq dev=8kHz, modulating signal=8sin(8000πt), carrier signal=10sin(100000πt), resistance
[image]

Comment: You need more here.  A link to the table you are using and what you don't understand.

Comment: **edit** your question to include info relevant to the question, rather than posting it as comments. The link, and what you think a relative amplitude is, definitely belong into the question itself!

Comment: and seriously, a link to google image search for "bessel table" doesn't illustrate **the least** what your question is (it feels like you wouldn't even know which specific bessel functions you're referring to, but are trying to make us pick for you). Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand what the modulation index is?  Read here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation#Modulation_index

Comment: Do you understand what "relative" means? Obviously, the sideband amplitude is going to be proportional to the carrier amplitude, and it is this ratio that the table is giving you.

Comment: @DaveTweed Why the sideband amplitude is proportional to the carrier amplitude and not the modulating amplitude?

Comment: It *is* a function of the modulating amplitude -- that's what the table is all about. See @GeorgeHerold's reference above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table gives you the sideband amplitude relative to the carrier amplitude.

The modulation amplitude gives you the modulation index, which allows you to find the right row of the table. The modulation index is the (modulation amplitude) / (modulation frequency), when both terms are measured in the same units, so both in Hz, or both in radians per second.

The column of the table gives you the offset of the sideband with respect to the modulation frequency, that is, the harmonic of the modulation.

So with a modulation index of zero, that is an unmodulated carrier, you can see that the zeroth sideband (the unmodulated carrier) is 1.00.